# Find documents between two dates with mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I've a problem where I need to create events. But, those events cant have an opening/ending time between another events. I want my events to get an opening/ending time were they will be the ONLY one at the range of those dates

For example, if I've an event which:

```
starts at: 4pm
ends at: 5pm
```

I cant have another event which:

```
starts at: 4:30 **( this opening time is between start/ends from above event )**
ends at: 5:30
```

same with:

```
starts at: 3pm
ends at: 6pm

**this one is containing the first event too**
```

this is the structure:

```
{ 
  "event" : "Event 1"
  "startDate": 2019-10-18T20:00:00.363Z, //
  "endDate": 2019-10-18T21:00:00.363Z // 
}
```

How can I solve this with mongo? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{$or:[
{$and:[{startDate: { $gte: new Date(data.startDate), $lte: new Date(data.endDate) }}]},
{$and:[{endDate: { $gte: new Date(data.startDate), $lte: new Date(data.endDate) }}]}
]}
```

First check whether there are any records in the database in between the given dates using the above query. If you get any records that means events already existed in between the given dates, so that you can just throw the exception otherwise store the record.